# Unknown method ApiTester::sendGet with Codeception

Tags: php, api, testing, codeception

I'm trying to setup some Codeception tests to test an API that I'm building but I seem to be doing something wrong.

Following a tutorial* I have run `php codecept.phar generate:suite api` which creates the ./tests/api.suite.yml file which looks like this:

```
class_name: ApiTester
    modules:
        enabled:
            - \Helper\Api
```

I modified this file to be the same as the one in the tutorial (adding my URL) like this:

```
class_name: ApiTester
    modules:
        enabled:
          - REST:
              url: http://serviceapp/api/v1/
              depends: PhpBrowser
```

And then generate a test script `generate:cept api ReadUser` and add my tests such as

```
<?php 

$I = new ApiTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('perform actions and see result');
$I->sendGet('/user/1');
```

However when I run the test I get the error `Call to undefined method ApiTester::sendGet`

What do I need to add to have methods like sendGet, sendPost and all the others available?

The Codeception version is 2.1.5

*http://codeception.com/docs/10-WebServices

Fixed: I removed the tests directory and started again and it is working now. Not sure what is different. Yii2 build the tests path initially so maybe it did something different.

Comment: Have you enabled the PhpBrowser module?

Answer (score 0):

It's important to pay attention to upper and lower case writing. The name of the method is `$I->sendGET()` (uppercase GET).

Try this

```
<?php 

  $I = new ApiTester($scenario);
  $I->wantTo('perform actions and see result');
  $I->sendGET('/user/1');
```

Comment: Function and method names are case insensitive in PHP.

Comment: nice joke Naktibalda.